# Does Django Cache the database's DNS info?

Tags: django, caching, dns, django-orm

Django seemingly not doing a DNS lookup when connecting to postgres

I have a route53 weighted CNAME record with a TTL of 1 second (just to test this) to load balance our read reps, however when i adjust the weights and test it out with dig, ensuring only one of the two read replica ips are being returned by the DNS, Django continues using the database ip from before the DNS swap.

Does Django cache the ip of its database to avoid DNS lookups? I expected it to lookup the database each time it connected with a conn_max_age of 0.

Comment: Were you able to find the cause?